# Why convert TeX to XML before compilation to PDF?

Tags: journal-publishing, xml

When I received the proof for my latest paper submission I found the following explanatory text in the proof:

> Please note that as part of the production process, [the journal] converts all
>   articles, regardless of their original source, into standardized XML
>   that in turn is used to create the PDF and online versions of the
>   article as well as to populate third-party systems such as Portico,
>   CrossRef, and Web of Science. We share our authors’ high expectations
>   for the fidelity of the conversion into XML and for the accuracy and
>   appearance of the final, formatted PDF. This process works
>   exceptionally well for the vast majority of articles; however, please
>   check carefully all key elements of your PDF proof, particularly any
>   equations or tables.

I have a few questions about this:

- Can someone explain, why this conversion is done?
- What system is (likely) used to generate the XML from TeX?
- What system is (likely) used to generate the PDF from XML?
- Could I, as an end user, incorporate such a conversion in my workflow and would it help me?

Comment: Is this question really related to (La)TeX?

Comment: working backwards through your questions: No, the systems are likely proprietary or very expensive, or both, depends on the journal, could be tex, in design, 3b2/APP, xyvision/XPP, unnamed internal typesetting systems, ..., could be anything, as it says in the quote the xml can be submitted to cross referencing and abstract databases, and unified publishing from other author supplied files (eg Word)

Comment: @phx My question is: What is the advantage of converting a (La)TeX file to XML before creating a PDF, and what are the tools required to do so? While I am aware that it is a broad question, I tried to make it more relevant to this site by adding the last question of how a TeX-XML conversion could be useful to users. And, honestly, I do not know a better place to ask such a question. Please direct me, if I am wrong.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have omitted the journal name and production company as I felt it not relevant to the main question. I am trying to understand the professional workflow and find possibilities for users to draw advantage of it.

Comment: Sure I would have answered same way had you mentioned the journal. Actually I've seen that notice before and putting it into google turns up several publications where it is included in the information for authors:-)

Comment: As an end user, you could use tex4ht to convert to DocBook, then XSLT / FOP to convert to PDF or other formats.

Comment: Another interesting LaTeX to HTML/XML converter: http://tiarno.github.io/plastex/

Answer (score 4):

Well, maybe it is just for LaTeX. Maybe they also accept Microsoft Word-based submissions. In that case, it would make some sort of sense to convert everything to a common format. I am not an expert for Word, but afaik, it can produce some kind of XML-based output already. Maybe they use some XSLT to convert that to some intermediate format. LaTeX could be converted to the same format, maybe in the same way as @user24582 suggested.

Then you can use a standardized way to convert the XML format to a pdf, again maybe in the same way as @user24582 suggested. The advantage would be to get the same kind of output for both Word and LaTeX files.

Also we do not know the history of the journal. Maybe they accepted only Word documents or only LaTeX documents in the past. If they had some kind of tool chain already involving the XML format, then adding a new input format by adding a converter from this particular format to the XML representation would be a logical step. This, of course, also holds for future formats. Say, maybe they want to be able to accept papers in different formats in the future, be it Open Office or whatever.

Another reason for XML could be that the may have tools which compute statistics over documents and/or perform spell checking. Having a unified way for spell checking which applies to different formats (such as Word and LaTeX) may be complicated.

Along that alley, we may also consider the way LaTeX handles non-English characters (or, at least, did that in the past). I am talking `ä` as `\"a`, for instance. That may be a problem for spell checking. Having a system which can translate all of that to nice unicode may be helpful.

Another reason might be readability. Having an XML format may drastically reduce the amount of things which can occur. Just look around this user group for all the oddities and strange things people here do. LaTeX code can become arbitrarily complex to read. If you are a journal and want to outsource or simplify your document processing, having a well-defined XML format which defines documents in a way more like HTML and less like a program (as in LaTeX) may be a good idea. I think the amount of people that can read HTML is much higher than the amount of people that can read LaTeX. And even amongst the people who can read LaTeX and HTML, I think the vast majority can read HTML documents faster, simply because of the strange things you can do in LaTeX, plus some mechanisms like floating objects. Hence, you may be able to higher proof readers or something at a much cheaper rate, since they simply need to know much less and/or may be able to process documents faster. Plus, again, that it would not matter anymore whether the document was originally a LaTeX document or a Word document.

Yet another issue may be the long-term storage of documents. If you have clearly defined XML format for your journal, along with code for type setting which is sort of version controlled, then you would feel more independent. There are extremely many LaTeX packages out there, and they may change over time. If you store LaTeX documents which use several packages for the long term, you may be afraid whether you still can compile them in 10 years. Or, at least, it may be harder to track down all the versions of the software you require. You may do that once, when the document comes in, transform it to your simple XML format, and then just hope that your format is documented well-enough and your typesetting software is maintained well-enough to still be functional in the far future.

And again, you can process XML documents easier if you want to extract information. You could use XSLT and XPATH and whatever to extract author names, references, image titles, sections, etc. (You can also do that with LaTeX, though, but I think it may be more complicated.)

These are some reasons that come to my mind. I do not want to claim that all of them are valid or even good, but at least these are things that I imagine that someone may say who would like to argue that XML is good in the document production process.